# Checkbox refreshing in false when I use notifyDataSetChanged();

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

My problem is the one wrote on the title, I have a recyclerview with checkboxes and radiobuttons before I started to use the notifyDataSetChanged() (because I need to update the recyclerview) the checkboxes and radiobuttons were been checked, but now the checks don't work. (I think that it work but it becomes false instantly)

I am sure of this because if I comment the line of `notifyDataSetChanged()` then it still working as well.

Do you guys know how to fix it?

Java for the adapter Class:

```
public class OptionModesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OptionModesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private int fatherMode;
private int fatherId;
private Context context;
private AsyncAdapters asyncAdapters;
private ArrayList<Modes> modes;
private ArrayList<Modes> selected;
private ArrayList<IUrbanRadioButton> radiosSelected;

OptionModesAdapter(ArrayList<Modes> modes, Context context, int fatherMode, AsyncAdapters asyncAdapters) {
    this.modes = modes;
    this.context = context;
    this.fatherMode = fatherMode;
    this.selected = new ArrayList<>();
    this.asyncAdapters = asyncAdapters;
    this.radiosSelected = new ArrayList<>();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CheckBox cbOptionMode;
    private IUrbanRadioButton rbOptionMode;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cbOptionMode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_option_mode);
        rbOptionMode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb_option_mode);
    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.option_modes, parent, false);
    return new OptionModesAdapter.ViewHolder(myView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (fatherMode) {
        case 0:
            holder.rbOptionMode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cbOptionMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rbOptionMode.setText(modes.get(position).getTranslationName(context));
            holder.rbOptionMode.setParentName(String.valueOf(modes.get(position).getIdFather()));
            onClickRadioButton(holder.rbOptionMode, position);
            break;
        case 1:
            holder.cbOptionMode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rbOptionMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.cbOptionMode.setText(modes.get(position).getTranslationName(context));
            onClickCheckBox(holder.cbOptionMode, position);
            break;
        default:
            Log.e(CustomConstants.EXCEPTION, "OptionModesAdapter: ln 72. Esto no es un modo admitido");
            break;
    }

}

private void onClickCheckBox(final CheckBox checkBox, final int position) {

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (selectedContainsCB(checkBox)) {
                removeOldCb(checkBox);
            } else {
                addNewCb(checkBox);
            }

            fatherId = modes.get(position).getIdFather();
            asyncAdapters.onInnerClicked(selected, false, fatherId);
        }
    });
}

private boolean selectedContainsCB(CheckBox checkBox) {
    Modes newMode = findModeByCheckBox(checkBox);

    return selected.contains(newMode);
}

private Modes findModeByCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
    Modes modeToReturn = new Modes();

    for (Modes currentMode : modes) {
        if (currentMode.getTranslationName(context).equals(checkBox.getText().toString())) {
            modeToReturn = currentMode;
            break;
        }
    }

    return modeToReturn;
}

private void removeOldCb(CheckBox checkBox) {

    Modes modeToRemove = findModeByCheckBox(checkBox);
    checkBox.setChecked(false);
    selected.remove(modeToRemove);

}

private void addNewCb(CheckBox checkBox) {
    Modes modeToAdd = findModeByCheckBox(checkBox);
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
    selected.add(modeToAdd);
}

private void onClickRadioButton(final IUrbanRadioButton iUrbanRadioButton, final int position) {

    iUrbanRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            settingFalseAllRadios();
            deletingAllModesRadios();
            addNewRb(iUrbanRadioButton);
            radiosSelected.add(iUrbanRadioButton);
            iUrbanRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            fatherId = modes.get(position).getIdFather();
            asyncAdapters.onInnerClicked(selected, true, fatherId);
        }
    });
}

private void settingFalseAllRadios() {
    for (IUrbanRadioButton iUrbanRadioButton : radiosSelected) {
        iUrbanRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    radiosSelected.clear();
}

private void deletingAllModesRadios() {
    selected.clear();
}

private Modes findModeByRadioButton(IUrbanRadioButton iUrbanRadioButton) {

    Modes modeToReturn = new Modes();

    for (Modes currentMode : modes) {
        if (currentMode.getTranslationName(context).equals(iUrbanRadioButton.getText().toString())) {
            modeToReturn = currentMode;
            break;
        }
    }

    return modeToReturn;
}

private void addNewRb(IUrbanRadioButton iUrbanRadioButton) {
    Modes modeToAdd = findModeByRadioButton(iUrbanRadioButton);
    selected.add(modeToAdd);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modes.size();
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the code of adapter class

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Hi, I let you there the Java for the Adapter Class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I just to solve that, I was calling notifyDataSetChanged() from the class which contain the Adapter. This is because the recyclerView were refreshing all the times and the checkboxes and radiobuttons don't be printed as checked.

The solution that works to me is calling the notifyDataSetChanged() inside the recyclerView. Just like this:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //My code...

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```